# Eclipse MARS.2 and svn 1.6.11 issue

Tags: eclipse, svn

Eclipse *replaces* `bin/...` sub-trees, which removes mandatory `.svn` directories. Thus, it is impossible to commit.

What is best practice for to work around this issue?

Found some information about svn version 1.8 not relying on `.svn` folders on each level in the folder tree. Is this true? If so, how to upgrade svn? yum update have not fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

The `bin` folder should not be added to svn as it is a derived source. You should remove it from the repository and add it to the ignore list.

Answer (score 0):

@Kai's answer is correct. In most cases you should not put `/bin` under version control. You should have [`svn:ignore`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html#svn.advanced.props.special.ignore) property configured to exclude `/bin` and other items that should not be version controlled. Read the documentation!

And yes, up-to-date Subversion clients have only one `.svn` metadata directory at the root of the working copy.

Subversion 1.6 is very old and is not longer supported for more than 3 years already (since 18 Jun 2013). You should upgrade to version 1.9 that is the latest and best SVN version in year 2016. Check the instructions of your SVN plugin that you use in Eclipse (Subclipse or Subversive, I guess).